# Cultures available in C# WPF Application

Tags: c#, reflection, resources

I am working on localization and pulling all the available cultures based on the folders created in bin. the name of the folders are then converted into culturesInfo.

```
if (!bFoundInstalledCultures)
{
    //determine which cultures are available to this application
    Debug.WriteLine("Get Installed cultures:");
    CultureInfo tCulture = new CultureInfo("");
    foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(Application.StartupPath))
    {
        try
        {
            //see if this directory corresponds to a valid culture name
            DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            tCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(dirinfo.Name);

            //determine if a resources dll exists in this directory that matches the executable name
            if (dirinfo.GetFiles(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath) + ".resources.dll").Length > 0)
            {
                pSupportedCultures.Add(tCulture);
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(" Found Culture: {0} [{1}]", tCulture.DisplayName, tCulture.Name));
            }
        }
        catch(ArgumentException e) //ignore exceptions generated for any unrelated directories in the bin folder
        {
        }
    }
    bFoundInstalledCultures = true;
```

Above code is part of one Runtime localization example on Codeproject.com

are there are any methods thru which we can get this Info and can we use reflection.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`CultureInfo.GetCultures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultures.aspx) to get all installed cultures:

```
//create an array of CultureInfo to hold all the cultures found, these include the users local cluture, and all the
//cultures installed with the .Net Framework
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);

//loop through all the cultures found
foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
{
    // ...
}
```